# Why does accessing a nil pointer in Go cause an Error in Inorder traversal

Tags: go, pointers, binary-tree

I have written inorder traversal in python which works fine.

```py
def inOrderTraverse(tree, array):
    if tree is None:
        return None
    inOrderTraverse(tree.left,array)
    array.append(tree.value)
    inOrderTraverse(tree.right,array)
    return array
```

However when I try to apply the same logic with GOlang, it does not work.

```
type BST struct {
    Value int

    Left  *BST
    Right *BST
}

func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse(array []int) []int {
    if tree == nil {
        return nil
    }
    (tree.Left).InOrderTraverse(array)
    array = append(array,tree.Value)
    (tree.Right).InOrderTraverse(array)
    return array
}
```

In order to fix this I write if statements to prevent the functions from being called if tree.Left is nil. However I am still confused why my original code does not work.

```
func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse(array []int) []int {
    if tree.Left != nil {
        array = tree.Left.InOrderTraverse(array)
    }
    array = append(array,tree.Value)
    if tree.Right != nil {
        array = tree.Right.InOrderTraverse(array)
    }
    return array
}
```

To summarize, I am trying to write inorder traversal in Go using the same reasoning from python and it is not working. I figured out how to get it to work(the third code block), however I still do not understand why the second code block does not work. It seems like calling the function on the Nil pointer causes an error

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

In your 2nd block of code, the reason it does not work is because the result is discarded:

```
 // (tree.Left).InOrderTraverse(array) // the return result is ignored
 array = (tree.Left).InOrderTraverse(array) // capture it like so
```

`Python` uses pass by-reference; `Go` passes by value. As such it can get tricky especially when modifying things like `slices` in Go.

Since you're already returning the results of the traversal, passing in the `array` is actually redundant.

---

Pulling this all together to fix both left & right traversal - and using a return variable `result`:

```
func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse() (result []int) {
    if tree == nil {
        return // implicitly returns empty `result`
    }

    result = append(result, (tree.Left).InOrderTraverse()...)
    result = append(result, tree.Value)
    result = append(result, (tree.Right).InOrderTraverse()...)

    return // implicitly returns `result`
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/AUvgZTABiU9

---

***EDIT***

A `Go` *"pass by reference"* implementation - where the `results` slice is passed between calls - looks very similar to your `python` implementation:

```
func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse(result *[]int) {
    if tree == nil {
        return
    }

    (tree.Left).InOrderTraverse(result)

    *result = append(*result, tree.Value)

    (tree.Right).InOrderTraverse(result)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Pp9-4-y-lmE

Note: `*[]int` (i.e. a pointer to `[]int`) is needed here, as the slice capacity will change during the recursion. A slice is really just a [header with a backing array](https://go.dev/blog/slices) - so while a function can change a slice's elements - even when copied by value - it cannot make the slice shrink or grow (as is the case here). Passing a pointer allows the slice to be reassigned to a potentially larger backing array.